# Is there a way to somewhat automate a Double Elimination bracket on google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, tournament, double-elimination

I'm looking for some help in trying to automate a double elimination bracket that I created on Google sheets. I won't pretend to know much about it. I'm mostly self taught on anything when it comes to sheets and I know that it requires an if/then solution but I think I've come to a road block and require assistance from people that actually know how to do it.

Basically I'm running a double elimination tournament. A player has to lose twice in order to be completely eliminated. I'd like to make it so that when I type W in a cell, it takes the data from the cell to the left of it (Player 1 in the screenshot) and puts it into the next round in the cell noted by the arrow. I'd also like to make it so that if I typed L instead, it would take the data from the cell to the left of it and put the name (Player 2 in the screenshot) into the losers bracket. "Player 1-16" are placeholder names, as I'll have real names in the lookup sheet I have hidden once its ready.

Is any of this possible? Or am I being too ambitious at this point? I could do this manually for sure, but since I'm gonna have other people helping when I'm not around, I'd rather it be a simple W or L so that they don't mess around with other aspects of the sheet(s).

I would appreciate ANY and all assistance. I've attached a screenshot and a link to the sheet so that you can copy and mess around with it. Thank you in advance!

[Double Elim Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hh1k4MV9Ed1ZZqoT48pAP3HQkxFBsUMfPMJLPQhajN0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Double Elim Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qosS0.png)

EDIT 3/18 6:30PM EST: The furthest I've gotten through the use of IF(OR is the screenshot below. If I put W, it bring 'Player 1' to I6. If E4 is left blank or has L instead, I6 says 'FALSE' instead. This is where I'm having the most trouble. How do I continue from here, and how do I also take into account C5 & E5 for I6?

[Double Elim Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsbyH.png)

Answer (score 0):

try in C39:

```
=FILTER(C4:D5, E4:E5="L")
```